# Allow socket connection to Windows 7 VM on Mac Host

Tags: vmware-fusion

I have a Windows 7 Pro running as guest under VMWare Fusion OSX 10.10.5.

I want to run a program on windows 7 that listens on a port.
I want to connect to that port from outside of my Mac.

This VM is running in "Share with my Mac" mode and "Private to my Mac" mode and I would like to leave it that way.

I have identified the following things that need to be configured:

1. Configure VMWare to pass the port onto the VM
2. Configure the Mac firewall to allow the connection
3. Configure the Windows firewall to allow the connection

I have done that and I still cannot connect.

I start the server program on Windows, then I used telnet to try to connect.

I can connect if I connect completely within Windows.

Is there something else that needs to be configured?
What are some tips for debugging this?

Addendum:

### Configuring VMWare:

https://encyclopediaofdaniel.com/blog/fusion-dhcp-port-forwarding/
    In a nutshell:
`sudo vim /Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/vmnet8/nat.conf`
and make it look like this:

```
[incomingtcp]

# Use these with care - anyone can enter into your VM through these...
# The format and example are as follows:
#<external port number> = <VM's IP address>:<VM's port number>

1020 = 172.16.46.128:1020
```

### Configuring Mac Firewall:

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-open-specific-ports-in-os-x-1010-firewall-3616405/

In a nutshell
   `sudo vim /etc/pf.conf`

### Configuring Windows Firewall:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-port-windows-firewall#1TC=windows-7

In a nutshell:

1. Go to Control Panel -> Firewall -> Advanced Settings.
2. Note you are on "Windows Firewall with Advanced Settings" dialog
3. Goto "Inbound Rules" and click on "New Rule"